# JQGrid Custom header row on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I can do this by manually prepending to the grid, but I'm trying to figure out a JQGRID way to create a header row with buttons.

I'm thinking I need to customize the `navbar` somehow but I'm not sure how.

This is what I am looking to do.

(picture below)
[image: table with custom header]

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomPager.htm). It display the results which are very close to what you need.

[image]

local paging with "First", "Previous", "Next" and "Last" buttons works like in the original grid.

I think that you will be able to modify the demo to your exact requirements yourself.

The code which I used in the demo:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    ...
    toppager: true,
    pginput: false,
    recordpos: "center",
    pagerpos: "left",
    recordtext: "Errors {0} - {1} of {2}"
});

var $table = $('<table class="ui-pg-table" style="table-layout: auto;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>'),
    $row = $table.find(">tbody>tr");
$table.appendTo("#list_toppager_right");
$("#next_t_list_toppager").appendTo($row);
$("#last_t_list_toppager").appendTo($row);
$("#list_toppager_left").width(70);
$("#list_toppager_right").width(70);
```

The ids used in the code includes "list" substring which is the `id` of the grid. One should change the names is another name are used.